# Access to tables

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I want to make sql queries to these tables in oracle:

```
GV$INSTANCE
SYS.V_$DATAFILE
DBA_DATA_FILES
DBA_FREE_SPACE
V$SESSION
DBA_JOBS_RUNNING
DBA_SCHEDULER_JOBS
DBA_SCHEDULER_JOB_CLASSES
V$SESSION
V$SESSTAT
V$STATNAME
GV$SESSION
GV$SESSTAT
GV$STATNAME
GV$PROCESS
V$RMAN_BACKUP_JOB_DETAILS
```

How I can give access to them?

Answer (score 1):

As far as i understood the question you need to access these tables. Now ther are two ways by which you can access these.

**1 Direct Object level GRANT**

So to give access with Direct object level Grant
So you need to connect as sysdba and provide GRANTS eg

```
GRANT SELECT ON V$SESSION TO <USER>; -- Direct GRANT
```

**2. Access via Oracle Roles**

Assume `SELECT_ROLE` a existing role to which SELECT Grants re provided for the required objects.

```
GRANT SELECT_ROLE TO <USER>;
```

Hope this helps.